# Reach router <Router>: Children of <Router> must have a `path`

Tags: path, reach-router

i want to read the url in the clientProvider and then render the rest of the app but it throws this error :

: Children of  must have a `path` or `default` prop, or be a `<Redirect>`. None found on element type `[object Object]`

Here are my 2 classes

App.js

```
<LocationProvider>
  <Router basepath={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <ClientProvider path="/:clientID">
      <CssBaseline />
      <AuthProvider>
        <UserProvider>
          <BusinessLog path="/" />
          <VisitorLog path="visitorLog" />
          <VisitorAccess path="visitorAccess" />
          <DataAccess path="dataaccess" />
        </UserProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ClientProvider>
  </Router>
</LocationProvider>
```

And the CLientProvider after reading the url

```
 return loadingClient ? (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <CircularProgress />
 

   </div>
  ) : (

        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <ClientContext.Provider value={client}>{props.children}</ClientContext.Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

// instead of this

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
```

// do this

```
<Redirect path="/" to="/home" />
```